# How to combine 3 collections MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have 3 collections: Restaurants, Menu and Product.

Their structure:

[**Restaurants**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaUDF.png)

[**Menu**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJxMo.png)

[**Products**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITXBI.png)

I want to make a query with nested arrays. And try:

```
const restaurant = await Restaurant.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "menus",
            "localField": "menu",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "menu",
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "products",
            "localField": "menu.products",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "menu.products"
        }
    },
])
```

But this query returns data without menu name:

```
"menu": {
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "604f349280a17606402211d3",
            "price": 6,
            "image": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/00/67/1e/00671e890191ecfeaf680cbecd3acf3e.jpg",
            "name": "Toast with banana",
            "description": "210g, Composition: Bread, Nutella, Banana",
            "user": "604f349280a17606402211d0",
            "__v": 0,
            "createdAt": "2021-03-15T10:18:58.220Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-03-15T10:18:58.220Z"
        },...]
```

I just started to study Mongodb, so I don't understand a lot. Please help write a request.

If I wrote something wrong, sorry, English is not my first language :)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be done like this

```
const restaurant = await Restaurant.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "menus",
            "localField": "menu",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "menu",
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": { "path": "$menu", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "products",
            "localField": "menu.products",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "menu.products"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": { "$first": "$name" },
            "hours": { "$first": "$hours" },
            "image": { "$first": "$image" },
            "phones": { "$first": "$phones" },
            "takeAway": { "$first": "$takeAway" },
            "description": { "$first": "$description" },
            "address": { "$first": "$address" },
            "user": { "$first": "$user" },
            "menu": { "$push": "$menu" }
        }
    }
])
```